# Java. read(char [] c, int offset, int len) не срабатывает смещение

Tags: java, файлы, методы, текст

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static String Reader (String path, int offset, int length) {
        String string = "";
        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(path);
            char[] buf = new char[length+offset];
            reader.read(buf,offset,length);
            for (int i=0; i<length+offset; i++) {
                string += buf[i];
            }
        }
        catch (IOException exception){
            System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
        }
        return string;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Reader("D:/daile.txt",5,10));
    }
}
```

Написал метод, который по-идее должен считывать из текстового файла по расположению (path) определенное количество символов (length), со смещением на (offset) символов. Но смещение не работает. Считывает все символы на длину length.
В чем проблема?

Comment: Эникейщик, но в выводе нет 5 пробелов. Сразу написана строка из первых 10 символов. Видимо, не хватает какого-то функционала в методе, а какого не понимаю.

Comment: Не туда комментируете :) 5 пробелов есть, просто их не видно же. Замените 5 на 10 или 0, станет видно, что строка начинается в другой позиции.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`offset` работает, но не так, как вы думаете. Этот параметр указывает с какого места сохранять прочитанное в результат, а не с какого места читать `path` ([описание метода](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#read(char[],%20int,%20int))). В выводе результата в самом начале 5 пробелов. Это как раз ваш `offset`.

Здесь нужен метод [skip(long n)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#skip(long)):

```
    reader.skip(offset);
    reader.read(buf,0,length);
```

Ну и поскольку считывается `length` символов, то и `buf` достаточно сделать длиной `length`:

```
char[] buf = new char[length];
```

И точно так же подкорректировать цикл:

```
for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
```

Итого:

```
try {
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(path);
    char[] buf = new char[length];
    reader.skip(offset);
    reader.read(buf,0,length);
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
        string += buf[i];
    }
```

Comment: С reader.skip(offset); все заработало как надо!
Спасибо за помощь. Сейчас почитаю про этот метод подробнее. )